# Not receiving messages via azure service bus queue

Tags: node.js, azure, azureservicebus

I have a C# program sending messages to an Azure service Bus Q (on VM).  The messages *should* be received by a node.js application (on Mac).  Problem is the receive.  The behaviour I see is:

- If I start the node.js app in a new term window with a message already in the Q, it is received on the first call
- Keeping the node.js app running, the next message posted to the Q will be received after 1 min
- stopping the node.js app and restarting it in the same term window and posting another message to the Q is never received

I know that the C# program is correctly sending the message as I inspect with service bus explorer immediately after the program confirms "send".  The send is being done currently in synchronous mode.

Node.js program: (running with latest azure library and node 8.9.4)

```
logger.info("Connecting to service bus");
const sbService = azure.createServiceBusService(connectionString);
if (sbService != null) {
 sbService.createQueueIfNotExists(queueName, function (err) {
   if (err) {
     logger.error("Cannot connect to "+queueName+" :: "+ util.inspect(err, { depth: null }));
   } else {
      logger.info("Connected to Q :: processing begins ");
      var intervalID = setInterval(timerElapsed, 5000);
   }
 });
}

function timerElapsed() {
  sbService.receiveQueueMessage(queueName, { isPeekLock: false }, function (err, lockedMessage) {
      if (err) {
          if (err !== 'No messages to receive') {
            logger.error("receiveQueueMessage error states: "+ util.inspect(err, { depth: 2 }));
          } else {
            console.log('.');
          }
       } else {
         logger.info("received Message: "+ util.inspect(lockedMessage, { depth: 2 }));
       }
  });
}
```

[EDIT] - Interestingly, I used the example from MS Github here [github example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/serviceBus) with similar results.

Answer (score 0):

<**bangs head on table**>  Look at the clues in this post [delays using python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/345).  The culprit is queue partitioning which is on by default.  Turn it off, and voila...